# Variable expanding inside BibLaTeX \addbibresource

Tags: biblatex, arguments, variable

I am working with a custom class provided by my university for the typesetting of thesis. The class automatically includes BibTex references in the document. I want to modify the class to make it work with BibLaTex. In the class, the .bib file path is passed from the document to the class via a command. The problem is that BibLaTeX command `\addbibresource{}` cannot process a variable as its input. See the MWE below for more details.

Is there a command I can use to expand the variable before it is processed by `\addbibresource{}`?

## MWE

### Main document

```
\documentclass{test}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\ConfigurationDocument{fichiers-references = {references.bib}}

\begin{document}
\cite{franssila_introduction_2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### test.cls

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplClass{test}{2018/09/26}{2.0}{MWE}

\tl_new:N \g_fichiers_references_tl

\LoadClass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{xparse,etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=ieee, url=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \ConfigurationDocument { m }
{ \keys_set:nn { udes-genie-these } { #1 } }

\keys_define:nn {udes-genie-these}
{
    fichiers-references .tl_gset:N = \g_fichiers_references_tl,
    fichiers-references .value_required:n = true,
}

\addbibresource{\g_fichiers_references_tl}
```

### references.bib

```
@book{franssila_introduction_2010,
        location = {Chichester, {UK}},
        edition = {2e édition},
        title = {Introduction to microfabrication},
        publisher = {Wiley},
        author = {Franssila, Sami},
        date = {2010}
    }
```

### Error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \g 
              _fichiers_references_tl
l.21 \addbibresource{\g_fichiers_references_tl}
```

Comment: AFAICS there are several issues here: One is related to how `biblatex` treats the argument of `\addbibresource` to sanitise potentially problematic file names, which means that `\g_fichiers_references_tl` is carried on and expanded in the wrong context (at least I think that is the problem) - I could get around that with the un-LaTeX3-y `\expandafter\addbibresource\expandafter{\g_fichiers_references_tl}`. But then the second issue kicks in: When `\addbibresource` is executed in your class file, the option has not been set and the variable `\g_fichiers_references_tl` is empty.

Comment: I suggest you just let your users use `\addbibresource` themselves. If you are worried about compatibility or want to be able to switch between systems, define a higher-level replacement.

Comment: Maybe you can avoid the `\expandafter\addbibresource\expandafter{\g_fichiers_references_tl}` by defining an `expl3` wrapper for `\addbibresource` and using the `V`/`v` version of that command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a `clist` for your references instead of a `tl` variable.

Then you can use `\clist_map_function:NN \g_fichiers_references_clist \addbibresource` inside `\ConfigurationDocument` to add each bibliography resource.

This has the advantage that you can add multiple references in the same key:

```
\ConfigurationDocument{fichiers-references = {references.bib, biblatex-exmaples.bib}}
```

So `test.cls` becomes:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplClass{test}{2018/09/26}{2.0}{MWE}

\clist_new:N \g_fichiers_references_clist

\LoadClass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=ieee, url=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \ConfigurationDocument { m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { udes-genie-these } { #1 }
  \clist_map_function:NN \g_fichiers_references_clist \addbibresource
}

\keys_define:nn {udes-genie-these}
{
    fichiers-references .clist_gset:N = \g_fichiers_references_clist,
    fichiers-references .value_required:n = true,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And the bonus feature is awesome!