# Biblatex: filter entries by keyword and include crossref parents in bbl?

Tags: biblatex

I am using the sourcemap given in [this TeX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507668/303910) to filter `\nocite{*}` by keyword. This approach has some problems when using `crossref` inheritance, however.

Because *every* entry is `nocite`d, even entries which would otherwise be added to the `.bbl` file by `crossref` are filtered out by this sourcemap if they don't have the relevant keyword. In some sense, this is desirable behavior, since I only want entries with the relevant keyword to be included in the printed bibliography. But it also has the undesirable effect that entries which I do want to include fail to inherit via `crossref`.

An obvious workaround is to add the relevant keyword to the parent entry too. But as mentioned, this causes the entry to appear in the printed bibliography as well. I would like to avoid this, and rather for parent entries of entries with the relevant keyword to be 1) automatically included in the `.bbl` file and 2) included in the printed bibliography according to the `mincrossrefs` parameter setting.

Is there a different way to get the result I want, using sourcemaps or otherwise?

See my MWE below. The desired behavior is that `inbookb` and `inbookc` appear in the printed bibliography with the `date` and `booktitle` inherited from `bookb` and `bookc` (respectively), without `bookb` and `bookc` being included in the printed bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
  @book{booka,
    author = {Author Name},
    date = {2000},
    title = {Book Title},
    keywords = {include},
  }

  @inbook{inbooka,
    crossref = {booka},
    title = {Chapter Title},
    keywords = {include},
  }

  @book{bookb,
    author = {Author Name},
    date = {2001},
    title = {Second Book},
    keywords = {},
  }

  @inbook{inbookb,
    crossref = {bookb},
    title = {Second Chapter},
    keywords = {include},
  }

  @book{bookc,
    author = {Author Name},
    date = {2002},
    title = {Yet Another Book},
    keywords = {},
  }

  @inbook{inbookc,
    crossref = {bookc},
    title = {Yet Another Chapter},
    keywords = {},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,%
  ]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[nocited, final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, notmatch=include, final]
      \step[entrynull]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \cite{inbookc}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, this is one of the classical cases where too many advanced features are involved and it is not quite clear (at least to me) how they should ideally interact (taking into account the expectations/use cases people have for the involved features). If you can formulate a concrete feature request that looks like it would be useful for other people as well, please don't hesitate to head over to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.

Comment: @moewe Done! https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1345

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** 2024-03-18: Looks like this option doesn't work for larger `.bib` files due to memory constraints; switching to LuaLaTeX helped for a while before my file once again got too large. I wouldn't be surprised if I could make my regex a little more memory-efficient, but probably my best option to is to write an external script to produce my list of entry keys, possibly using the `btparse` library instead of regexes.

---

I have come up with an ugly but good enough solution to my problem, using regexes to parse the `.bib` file and extract the relevant entry keys.

The relevant code is given below; `\jobname.bib` and `include` are the relevant values to change if you're going to reuse it:

```
\file_get:nnN {\jobname.bib} {
    \cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab
    \endlinechar=10~
} \l_tmpa_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { [^@]*@[a-z]+\{([^\,]+,)[^@]*keywords\ =\ \{[^\}]*include[^@]* } { <\1> } \l_tmpa_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { (?:^|>)[^><]*(?:$|<) } { } \l_tmpa_tl
%\str_set:NV \l_tmpa_str \l_tmpa_tl
\clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\nocitetagged}{}{
  \clist_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_clist \nocite
}
```

Here is the full MWE corresponding to the one in the question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
  @book{booka,
    author = {Author Name},
    date = {2000},
    title = {Book Title},
    keywords = {include},
  }

  @inbook{inbooka,
    crossref = {booka},
    title = {Chapter Title},
    keywords = {include},
  }

  @book{bookb,
    author = {Author Name},
    date = {2001},
    title = {Second Book},
    keywords = {},
  }

  @inbook{inbookb,
    crossref = {bookb},
    title = {Second Chapter},
    keywords = {include},
  }

  @book{bookc,
    author = {Author Name},
    date = {2002},
    title = {Yet Another Book},
    keywords = {},
  }

  @inbook{inbookc,
    crossref = {bookc},
    title = {Yet Another Chapter},
    keywords = {},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,%
  ]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\file_get:nnN {\jobname.bib} {
    \cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab
    \endlinechar=10~
} \l_tmpa_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { [^@]*@[a-z]+\{([^\,]+,)[^@]*keywords\ =\ \{[^\}]*include[^@]* } { <\1> } \l_tmpa_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { (?:^|>)[^><]*(?:$|<) } { } \l_tmpa_tl
%\str_set:NV \l_tmpa_str \l_tmpa_tl
\clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\nocitetagged}{}{
  \clist_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_clist \nocite
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \cite{inbookc}
  \nocitetagged
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I found these TeX.SE answers helpful: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647305/303910), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460217/303910).